# Schema for a tags system

Tags: mongodb, meteor, database-schema

I am using Meteor to develop a web application. I am doing a tags system where a topic can be assigned zero or more tags. **I want to show 10 related topics at the bottom based on tags of the current topic**. I have two schemas in mind

Option 1:

Topics:

```
{
    _id: {
        type: String,
        optional: false,
        unique: true
    },
    name: {
        type: String,
        max: 255,
        optional: false
    }
    //other fields..
}
```

Tags:

```
{
    _id: {
        type: String,
        optional: false,
        unique: true
    },
    name: {
        type: String,
        max: 255,
        optional: false
    }
    //other fields..
}
```

TopicsTags

```
{
    tagId: {
        type: String,
        optional: false
    },
    topicId: {
        type: String,
        optional: false
    }
}
```

In this option, `TopicsTags` is the junction table that contains relationship between topics and tags

Option 2:

Topics:

```
{
    _id: {
        type: String,
        optional: false,
        unique: true
    },
    name: {
        type: String,
        max: 255,
        optional: false
    },
    tags: {
       type: [String]
    }
    //other fields..
}
```

Tags:

```
{
    _id: {
        type: String,
        optional: false,
        unique: true
    },
    name: {
        type: String,
        max: 255,
        optional: false
    }
    //other fields..
}
```

In this option there is additional field that contains all tag ids. I want to know which one is better for querying the top 10 related topics based on most common tags for meteor and mongodb. It would be better if you guys can point out to any online resource on how to query the top posts containing the tags of selected topic. I have searched but unable to get enough information.

I know that the second approach will be complex when we add new tags to a topic but that is fine as long as the reads are quick.

**EDIT**
Main question is which schema is better (or has possibility) to get related topics. For example, if "Topic 1" got "Tag 1", "Tag 2", "Tag 3". I want to get top 10 related topics in the following preference

1. Other topics which have all three tags ("Tag 1", "Tag 2", "Tag 3").
2. If the above criteria has less than 10 records then I want remaining records with two tags (("Tag 1" and "Tag 2") or ("Tag 2" and "Tag 3") or ("Tag 1" and Tag 3")
3. If the above two criteria combined has less than 10 records then I want remaining records with at least one of the tags ("Tag 1" or "Tag 2" or "Tag 3")

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I would include tag info (which you want to show along with a topic) as an array in topics document itself. You will read this information more than you update it. A tag for a topic is not something that frequently changes.

Comment: Just updated the question. The main problem for me is that I don't know whether it is possible using one of the two schemas to get related topics as per the mentioned criteria.

Comment: Agreed with @Areca. Also given, MongoDB's list of array operators, I think it would not be very difficult to achieve what OP wants.